# lmingwex and lmingw32 not found in Msys2

Tags: go, mingw-w64, msys2

I am working with `go version go1.19 windows/amd64` installed on `MSYS2 MINGW64`

On running command `go build`, I get following error:

```
I:\msys2\mingw64\lib\go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64\link.exe: running g++ failed: exit status 1
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: cannot find -lmingwex: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: cannot find -lmingw32: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is occurring with multiple source files.

How can this problem be solved?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem by executing these commands into your Terminal:

```bash
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-g++
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-libwinpthread-git
```

Comment: `mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-g++`  is not found.  I have installed remaining 2.